# My dynamically created CheckBox click event handler is not firing

Tags: vb.net, winforms, dynamic

I am writing a windows app to manage servers(apache,nginx,tomcat,etc) for developers. I create controls dynamically for each server as they are driven by configuration. I have managed to create handlers for the buttons, and comboboxes without an issue but the handler for the checkboxes does not fire. I think I am doing exactly the same but obviously I am missing something.

This is the handler. There is only one for all the Checkboxes

```
Private Sub AddTheCheckboxClick(rCheckBox As CheckBox)
    AddHandler rCheckBox.Click, Sub(rSender, rEventargs)
                                    Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
                                    Dim lStatus As Boolean = False
                                    Cursor = Cursors.Default
           'do some stuff here for the relevant server

                                End Sub
End Sub
```

I place a break at the top of the handler, run the app, click on the checkbox and it does not fire.

This code copies the control from a template to the relevant place in the screen and then adds the handler. The whole set of controls. is created once per server.

```
'Service checkbox
.Controls.Add(CopyPlaceControl(lDinamicListview, chkServerService, lLocation, True, lGenericServer))
AddTheCheckboxclick(chkServerService)

'Server switch and button click event handler
lNewServerSwitch = CopyPlaceControl(lDinamicListview, bServerSwitch, lLocation, True, lGenericServer)
.Controls.Add(lNewServerSwitch)
AddThebuttonclick(lNewServerSwitch)
```

I have seen a reply for a similar query for ASP and it was resolved by setting the AutoPostback property to true but this property does not exist in vb.net and it is probably irrelevant in my context.

I have also tried to call the event explicitly in the code just to check it fires when called but I have not found any way of doing so. It is easy for a button as in .Performclick() but I have not found one for a Checkbox.

Comment: What does `chkServerService` do? How are you creating/initializing the CheckBoxes (not adding them to a container)?

Comment: For the button, you are assigning the return of `CopyPlaceControl` to a variable (`lNewServerSwitch )before adding the variable to the controls collection and calling `AddThebuttonclick`; however you are following a different pattern for the checkbox.  Possibly that is the source of the problem.

Comment: Yep sorry, I meant to say "What does `CopyPlaceControl` do?"

Comment: `resolved by setting the AutoPostback property to true but this property does not exist in vb.net`  This isn't a "vb.net" issue.  It's a WinForms vs ASP.Net issue.  Different platforms.

Comment: I am kicking myself I did not see it. The template control gets added instead of the dynamically generated one. All working now. Thank you guys so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `CopyPlaceControl` method will create new control based on given one(`chkServerService`) and then new control added to the `.Control` collection.
However you adding click handler to the original checkbox(`chkServerService`) not to he new one.

```
'Service checkbox
Dim newCheckBox = 
    CopyPlaceControl(lDinamicListview, chkServerService, lLocation, True, lGenericServer)
AddTheCheckboxclick(newCheckBox)

.Controls.Add(newCheckBox)
```